# JVector Interactive Map not Rendering in Rails 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jvectormap

I've been trying to use this really cool JVector Interactive map plugin with my Rails 3 app but I must be doing something wrong because the map is not rendering. I haven't used JQuery much with Rails so am kind of new at this. I created a controller called Maps and a view called Intro.html.erb, which included my html from this tutorial: http://developer.practicalecommerce.com/articles/2988-Create-an-Interactive-Map-with-jVectorMap

I also split up my .js functions by putting them in application.js. Since that didn't work I found some other code that I tried to put in my Intro.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/javascripts/jquery.vector-map.css"     type="text/css" media="screen" />   
    <script src="public/javascripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="public/javascripts/jquery.vector-map.js"></script>
    <script src="public/javascripts/world-en.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function(){
       $('#map').vectorMap();
    });
   </script>
 </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It's still not rendering. I'm trying to run this in my development environment and am pointing locally to the files. For example: ***public/javascripts/world-en.js"***

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any error messages in the console? Are all the JS files actually being loaded?

Comment: Nope, no errors. I even tried a small test using a javascript alert popup dialogue box and it worked. But how do I know for sure if the JVector .js files are being loaded?

Comment: Check in Firebug/console/etc. of the browser and make sure it's listed in the collection of scripts.

Comment: Ok, I checked Firebug and verified that my jquery files for the JVector Map are not being loaded with error 404 not found. So it's something with the path. This helps a lot! Thanks.

Comment: Do you know where the .js plugin files are supposed to go in a Rails app?

Comment: They can go anywhere that's publicly accessible. Normally you'd use a javascript_tag to load them; it handles building the URL for you.

Comment: I finally have a map! I had to list out each .js file individually in my application.html.erb instead of using: <%= javascript_include_tag :default %>

Comment: You can also define the javascript files you want loaded by default in config/application.rb if you get bored of typing ;) Glad you worked it out.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use "world map" but in your finction you are defining the"#map". Here is the correct code you may try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>jVectorMap demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
  <script src="scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="world-map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $('#world-map').vectorMap();
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the folder with docs you need. Download and unzip the following [folder](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/41007907/scripts.zip) to you htdocs on your local host

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, fixed by specifing the imported map into the js initialization

```
  $('#world-map').vectorMap(
  {
    map: 'world-en',
  }
```